# JS, await with new

Tags: javascript, асинхронность

Всем привет. Помогите пожалуйста подружить асинхронность c оператором new.
Задача такая, есть функция-конструктор которая настраивает объект перед использованием. Одна из настроек - загрузка картинки. Происходит не мгновенно. Здесь по хорошему нужно загрузку картинки обернуть в промисиз и заивейтить код в этом месте. Но getApp -это не асинхронная функция, а конструктор. Я не пойму как подружить конструктор и await. 
Вот пример условного кода:

```
function getApp(width, ctx) {
   const wh = width;
   const ln = 1,5*width;
   const img = new Image;
   const img.src = spritesSrc; // с этого момента код побежал дальше а ресурс еще грузится.Нужно эвейтить. 
    return {
       render() {
           ctx.draw(img....)
           ...
}

...
const app = new getApp(100, ctx)
app.render();
....
```

Comment: Скорее всего никак. Почему бы не переделать getApp в асинхронную функцию?

Comment: судя по тому, что у вас в getApp находится return - это таки функция, а не конструктор

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
async function getApp(width, ctx) {...}
```

.

```
const app = await getApp(100, ctx)
```

Последний мною написаный код должен находиться внутри функции объявленной с использованием `async`.

Потому как оператор await заставляет функцию, ждать выполнения Promise и продолжать выполнение после возвращения Promise значения. Подробней тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await

Comment: вызов `new` тут лишний

Comment: Спасибо! Буду знать!

Answer (score 1):

Асинхронный конструктор, это не совсем хорошая идея. В вашем случае, вы еще возвращаете какой-то другой объект. Я бы предложил завести св-во, которое отображало бы процесс инициализации объекта и резолвилось бы после того, как с экземпляром можно работать

Синтетический пример

```js
class SomeClass {
  loaded = null
  prop = 0
  
  constructor() {
    // Делаем какую-то асинхронную операцию
    this.loaded = new Promise(resolve =>
      setTimeout(() => {
         this.prop = 10;
         resolve();
      }, 1000)
    );
  }
}

(async () => {
  const inst = new SomeClass();
  console.log('До инициализации: ', inst.prop);
  await inst.loaded;
  console.log('После инициализации: ', inst.prop);
})();
```

Пока что нельзя использовать `await` на самом верхнем уровне, но [пропозал](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) уже есть, когда его примут, можно будет убрать асинхронную функцию обертку