# JavaScript: сохранить значение цвета каждого пикселя изображения

Tags: javascript, изображения, canvas

Что я хочу сделать: загрузить изображение и считать его попиксельно, чтобы сохранить значение каждого пикселя.

Что я делаю:

```
let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let image = document.createElement("img");
image.setAttribute("src", imagePath);

canvas.width = image.width;
canvas.height = image.height;

let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

~ Попиксельное считывание изображения с использованием функции getImageData ~
```

Но есть проблема: размеры изображения равны 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю стоит дождаться когда картинка загрузится

```js
let imagePath = "https://via.placeholder.com/150";

let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
let image = document.createElement("img");

image.onload = function () {
  canvas.width = image.width;
  canvas.height = image.height;

  let context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, image.width, image.height);

  document.body.appendChild(canvas);
};
image.setAttribute("src", imagePath);
```

Comment: Спасибо, это работает. Но есть одна сложность: этот код выполняется в конструкторе класса и конечный список всех пикселей (pixels) мне нужно присвоить полю класса this.pixels. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Стоит задуматься действительно ли вам нужно пихать это в конструктор. Можно сделать статичный метод для создания экземпляра объекта. На [ruSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/995978/js-await-with-new) и на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43431550/async-await-class-constructor) есть обсуждения этого